# Why does the output always print j=5 in fork join_none?

Tags: multithreading, system-verilog, fork-join

I have a piece of code that exhibits the following behavior. I expected to see 10 parallel threads such that first thread: j=0 and fifth thread: j=4 , all run at simulation time 0 ns. Also, j=i and $display run in parallel, hence by the time $display executes, j is still x.

```
module tb;

integer i,j;

initial
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
fork
j = i; 
$display("Value of j is %d at time=%d \n", j, $time); 
join_none

endmodule
```

I am getting the following output. Can someone please explain. I tried on EDAPlayground using VCS.

```
Value of j is           5 at time=                   0 

Value of j is           5 at time=                   0 

Value of j is           5 at time=                   0 

Value of j is           5 at time=                   0 

Value of j is           5 at time=                   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that your code spawns 10 parallel threads. However, the `fork/join_none` does not start any of those threads until after the parent thread blocks or terminates. In your case, it's after the `initial` block process terminates. By that time, the value of `i` is 5 after exiting the `for` loop`.

Also, there is no defined execution order for the 10 threads - they are all in a race. The $displays or assignments can come in any order, so it is possible that `j` displays `x`. You may get different results from different tools

To get your code to display 0,1,...,4, you cannot use a static variable for `j`. You need a create a copy of `j` for each iteration of the `for` loop using an `automatic` that gets initialized with the current value of `i` for each loop. @Emman has shown one way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add an "automatic" to the variable before it starts executing, automatic storage class variables are mapped on the stack. When a function is called, all the local (non-static) variables declared in the function are mapped to individual locations in the stack. Since such variables exist only on the stack, they cease to exist as soon as the execution of the function is complete and the stack correspondingly shrinks. Meaning scope remains active until reaching end of all the child processes.

```
   module tb; 
      integer i,j;
      initial
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
          fork
            automatic int j=i;
            begin 
              $display("Value of j is %d at time=%d \n", j, $time); 
            end 
          join_none 
   endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But my question here is, not how to avoid this output but why this behavior is seen in my code and why is j=x not printed 5 times?

Comment: By default module or program block variable is static which means its memory is never de-allocated until simulation ends. In your case since the for loop value is updated to 5 in the first place j is updated to 5 since i holds value 5 and is never de-allocated which resulted in 5, but in the case automatic as mentioned in the answer only the memory is de-allocated once all the process were completed.